# Correct place to put colors of prompt (PS1)

Tags: command-line, bash, prompt

Say I want to change the colors of my PS1, or for the sake of simplicity I just want to change the content, so I want to do this:

```
PS1="touch me : "
```

My problem, doubt is:

1. If I put this in `.bash_profile`, every time I open a terminal I need to source it.
2. If I put it in `.profile`, the same, I need to explicitly source it.
3. It seems nasty to put this in `.bashrc` directly

Where should I locate this kind of configurations?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish ? why is it nasty to put your configuration in .bashrc ? .bashrc is probably best, but without knowing what your concerns are hard to give better advice.

Comment: I have read that bashrc should not be touched for this kind of configurations. Instead it should be put in another place. But I'm pretty ignorant with that.  I am trying to put some color on PS1 and show the branch if I am in a directory that has a git repository.

Answer (score 0):

`.bashrc` is considered the proper place for such configurations.

For details see:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizingBashPrompt

If you have concerns or someting to the contrary you read somewhere, you would need to express them or post a link for better advice.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use `.bash_login` for that.

From the bash manual:

> looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that
>   order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists

While it may be true that `.bashrc` is the most proper place to make these changes, there's a lot going on in there that I don't want to weed through when I am making edits. I like to keep the original files pristine. So I copy the original (smaller, more manageable) `~/.profile` to `~/.bash_login` and add my customizations to the end of that file.

One advantage is that if I suspect my customizations are contributing to some kind of problem, I can go back to the vanilla bash configuration by renaming or removing the .bash_login file. Without `.bash_login` the shell resorts to reading `.profile` again.